# Is there a shortcut to mute sound in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, shortcuts, mute

I keep accidentally muting my sound while playing a game, and I'm not sure how. Is there a shortcut I might be unknowingly executing? I'm certainly not using the windows key as I play.

Comment: Look in the game documentation or help file, it should be listed in there.

Answer (score 12):

Answer derived from @Randolf Richardson:

1) free utility called nircmd http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/nircmd.zip

2) create a shortcut: `"C:\Michal\Code\Mute Sounds\nircmd.exe" mutesysvolume 2`

3) set up shortcut key

EDIT / UPDATE: comment below is right / intention of the question is clear. Honestly I have no idea why did I answer this way :)

Comment: He's not lookking for any way to *deliberately* mute sound using a shortcut. He's looking for the reason why he's *inadvertently* muting sound (which is likely by triggering a keyboard shortcut).

Comment: That said, NirCmd is a very neat command line tool, with lots of functions! :-)

Comment: Whether or not the answer is satisfied, this post satisfies my google search. Thank you!

Answer (score 8):

It is also possible your keyboard has media functions built into it.

A lot of my function keys have media functions if I press them with the Fn key.

Answer (score 7):

<kbd>windows</kbd> + <kbd>x</kbd> contains an options to mute

and whole bunch of other options like:

1. brightness
2. mute
3. battery options
4. WiFi or connectivity
5. display or monitor or projector on off
6. sync services
7. presentation for office users

Comment: You are thinking of Windows 8/10 maybe?
The OP clearly stated Windows 7.
On Windows 7, without any scripts or hacks, Windows + X does nothing.

Answer (score 4):

You're probably pressing <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>s</kbd>. That tends to be the default sound effects shortcut for most games. Since most people play WASD this tends to cause issues at some point.

Answer (score 3):

This link describes how to set up a shortcut -- I mention this so that you can get an idea of where to look for possible causes of such a shortcut:

Desktop Shortcut | Keyboard Hotkey To Mute Sound
  http://www.technixupdate.com/desktop-shortcut-keyboard-hotkey-to-mute-sound/

If you happen to have one of those keyboards that has lots of extra function keys on it beyond the usual F1..F12 keys (as many high-end gamers do), it's possible that one of these keys might be configured to mute the sound -- is there a control panel for your keyboard that allows you to configure these extra keys (assuming you have such a keyboard)?

Answer (score -2):

If you like, you can use the `VolumeChanger.exe` from my project [muteFritz](https://sourceforge.net/projects/mutefritz/). The source code is also included in case you want to compile it on your own.

To toggle mute of the Systemsound you just have to start:

```
VolumeChanger.exe -t
```

The other options are:

```
-m = Mute
-u = unmute
-s = Help
-s 0.5 =  sets Soundvolume to 50%
```

Tested up to Windows 8.1. I guess for Windows XP it is not working, because the managmentsystem of the Windows sound was changed for Vista and any newer versions.

Comment: He's not lookking for any way to *deliberately* mute sound using a shortcut. He's looking for the reason why he's *inadvertently* muting sound (which is likely by triggering a keyboard shortcut).

Comment: Even though it's the wrong answer for the wrong question, it's a pretty good quality answer for a new user. Actually, *I was wrong*.

Comment: Whether or not the answer is satisfied, this post satisfies my google search. Thank you!

Answer (score -4):

FN + ESC toggles sound off/on.

Comment: Do you have a reference for this? I suspect this only works for some specific hardware with function keys.