# Win7 - mute sound in mixer for particular application by keyboard shortcut

Tags: windows-7, audio, mixer

I was wondering whether there is a way to mute / unmute a **particular** application in the mixer by a keyboard shortcut.

So e.g. by CTRL M W to mute / unmute the sound of Winamp. I am **not** asking about muting sound in general as in [Is there a shortcut to mute sound in Windows 7?](https://superuser.com/questions/253952/is-there-a-shortcut-to-mute-sound-in-windows-7), but the sound for a particular application.

[image]

Comment: In case anyone thinks of closing as duplicate the answer to http://superuser.com/questions/284527/where-are-the-vista-win7-volume-mixer-settings-stored doesn't appear to help as I can change the values stored in the registry but the mixer does NOT actually read the updated values to mute and unmute

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The solution is to use the freeware [nircmd](http://nircmd.nirsoft.net/) tool and create a desktop shortcut with whatever hotkey you'd like in order to run one of the following commands:

As documented at http://nircmd.nirsoft.net/changeappvolume.html

> changeappvolume [Process] [volume level] {Device Name/Index}
>
> **Examples:**
>
> changeappvolume iexplore.exe -0.2
>
> changeappvolume wmplayer.exe 0.55 Speakers
>
> changeappvolume /1275 -0.25 1
>
> changeappvolume Firefox.exe 0.5

Comment: update from 2017, now there is a specific command on nircmd called muteappvolume that does exactly what you desire. http://nircmd.nirsoft.net/muteappvolume.html